# What would be the purpose of this column in the database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I'm looking through my organization's database, and there is a table called dbo.Account_Alerts, and in it there is a column with a strange long name:

```
IsExpectedGreaterThanFieldMarginNotification(bit, null)
```

What would be the purpose of such a field? Is bit the same as Boolean ?

Thank You,
Adel

Comment: Probably, but I would suggest asking someone at your organisation rather than SO. It's _impossible_ for anyone to give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes bit is exactly a boolean. It can only be 1(true) or 0(false).

What I can assume for the purpose of this field is:

A Notification
which is due to a field which is greater in length as opposed to expected.

If High(1), then Notification shall be launched otherwise not.

(+Please note this understanding is my assumption only!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes bit is the same as boolean, and it can have a value of 1 (True) or 0 (False) and in your case it takes null values as well.

The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values; TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1.